# What kind of glue should I use for insulation to wood?

Tags: insulation, adhesive

I've got an unusual DIY underway. I'm making my own billiards table (pool table) cover. I started out cutting down two 4'x8' insulation sheets to set inside of the table's bunkers. I had to use two sheets to add up to the 1 & 3/4" height needed. Then I used a 4'x8' sheet of wood paneling (cheap) to cover the top of the table.

It fits well, but I'm having some trouble glueing it all together. I had to buy two different types of foam insulation, due to what was available in the thicknesses I needed. One foam sheet is purplish in color. The other is white foam with some sort of reflective material on both sides. The paneling is not very rigid, as it was the cheapest I could find.

So, I'm trying to figure out a good way to glue it all together. I tried to use a little bit of liquid nails, but I ran out. It didn't stick the foam to the wood paneling well enough and pulled apart. Any ideas? Thank you.

[image: paneling with foam]

Comment: If the bottom sheet of insulation is foil covered polyisocyanurate, you might want to see if you can find another sheet of extruded polystyrene (the purplish one on top). They glue much, much better than the foil does (you can even use a spray adhesive), and polyisocyanurate will degrade fairly quickly at the edges and will probably start to crumble with use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want *project adhesive*. It's like construction adhesive, but water based. The solvent in "heavy duty" construction adhesive dissolves the foam, which probably resulted in the poor bond you experienced. Project adhesive labels often mention foam as a typical use.

Be aware that water evaporates more slowly than solvents, and therefore your bonds require a longer cure time.

Liquid Nails is a brand name. The company makes both products.

Comment: Lots of liquid nail products out there, a neighbor tried to duplicate my cold room in his garage when laminating his foam insulation sheets he used liquid nails and a bunch of it ruined the first 2 sheets he was mad at me I showed him I have both kinds. The solvent type turned the foam into a gell what a mess.+

Comment: I picked up a tube of Liquid Nails Projects Construction Adhesive. I'm going to give it a try tonight to see if it will bond the three different types of materials. If that doesn't work, I'm pulling out the duct tape! lol